# emacs auto save for org-mode only

Tags: emacs, org-mode, autosave

I'm using auto save back to the original file for my org-mode but I only want it to work for this mode and nothing else.  Is that easy to do?

Here are my org-mode options

```
;; Org-mode options
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          'turn-on-visual-line-mode
          'auto-save-mode)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(lambda()
                (setq auto-save-visited-file-name t)
                (setq auto-save-interval 20)))
```

Note: For my full config please refer to https://github.com/map7/simple_emacs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should provide you with the customization of the auto-save file name just in org-mode.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-autosave-settings)
(defun my-org-mode-autosave-settings ()
  ;; (auto-save-mode 1)   ; this is unnecessary as it is on by default
  (set (make-local-variable 'auto-save-visited-file-name) t)
  (setq auto-save-interval 20))
```

*Note:* Your addition of `'auto-save-mode` in the `'org-mode-hook` would turn *off* auto save as it is on by default (unless you've turned it off globally).

Comment: This does not work for me using the Ubuntu 14.10 provided packages of org-mode 8.2.7 and Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: Solved: for this to work, one must run `(auto-save-mode t)` _after_ making the local variable `auto-save-visited-file-name` as the change does not take effect in an existing buffer without auto-save being re-enabled.

Comment: Instead can we disable auto save for a specific mode but keep it for all the other modes?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add an auto-save-hook.

```
(add-hook 'auto-save-hook 'org-save-all-org-buffers)
```

If you are using a shared folder or cloud based folder to sync your org files, you may also be interested in auto-revert for your org buffers as follows:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (auto-revert-mode 1)))
```